# Getting error implementing azure active directory dotnetcore webapp to webapi openidconnect

Tags: azure, .net-core, openid, access-token

Getting error implementing azure active directory dotnetcore webapp to webapi openidconnect

```
ClientCredential credential = new ClientCredential(AzureAdOptions.Settings.ClientId, AzureAdOptions.Settings.ClientSecret);
string userObjectID = (User.FindFirst("http://schemas.microsoft.com/identity/claims/objectidentifier"))?.Value;
AuthenticationContext authContext = new AuthenticationContext(AzureAdOptions.Settings.Authority, new NaiveSessionCache(userObjectID, HttpContext.Session));
AuthenticationResult result = await authContext.AcquireTokenSilentAsync(AzureAdOptions.Settings.TodoListResourceId, credential, new UserIdentifier(userObjectID, UserIdentifierType.UniqueId));
```

Getting below error

```
ErrorCode: failed_to_acquire_token_silently
Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.AdalSilentTokenAcquisitionException: Failed to acquire token silently as no token was found in the cache. Call method AcquireToken
```

Comment: Have you got the answer ?

Answer (score 0):

> Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory.AdalSilentTokenAcquisitionException: Failed to acquire token silently as no token was found in the cache. Call method AcquireToken

If **[no token is in the cache](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-dotnet/wiki/AcquireTokenSilentAsync-using-a-cached-token)**, `AcquireTokenSilentAsync` will throw an `AdalSilentTokenAcquisitionException`, and the application will need to calls `AcquireTokenAsync`.

Ensure your token cache is not in-memory so it doesn't get wiped in case of process restart.
Another thing you could do is increase the session duration. ASP.NET by default limits it to **20 minutes**, and `OpenIdConnect` by default follows that. It means it just erases those tokens after 20 minutes even though the refresh token is usable much longer.

For that you will need to modify the OpenIdConnect middleware registration in Startup.Auth.cs like so:

```
app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(
            new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
            {
                // ... Rest removed for brevity
                UseTokenLifetime = false
            });
```

Then in web.config set the session time to what you want:

```
<system.web>
  <sessionState timeout="720" /><!-- 12 hour session duration -->
</system.web>
```

For more details, you could refer to this [article](https://dzimchuk.net/adal-distributed-token-cache-in-asp-net-core/).